# Exchange Email Delete / Recreation Issue

Tags: exchange, exchange-2007, accounts

So I was having issues with a users mailbox to the point where I couldn't solve what was wrong so I deleted the account. I recreated the account with the same email address. Now users trying to email the address are getting odd returns

Generating server: EMAILSERVER.example.local

IMCEAEX-_O=EXAMPLE_OU=First+20administrative+20group_cn=recipients_cn=example1@examplecompany.com

## 550 5.1.1 RESOLVER.ADR.ExRecipNotFound; not found

Original message headers:

Received: from SI-SRV-EXCH.example.local ([::1]) by SI-SRV-Exch.example.local
 ([::1]) with mapi; Mon, 16 Jul 2012 21:21:41 -0700
Content-Type: application/ms-tnef; name="winmail.dat"
Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary
From: Jeff Lastname 
To: example1 lastname
    
Date: Mon, 16 Jul 2012 21:20:13 -0700
Subject: not able to connect to 10.0.0.20
Thread-Topic: not able to connect to 10.0.0.20
Thread-Index: AQHNY9Om6/bAzEFvb0KX+GOyZnLFAw==
Message-ID: <4658C83BD7D57D4EBAB0F1336F78858503B2D35FD7@SI-SRV-Exch.example.local>
Accept-Language: en-US
Content-Language: en-US
X-MS-Has-Attach:
X-MS-TNEF-Correlator: <4658C83BD7D57D4EBAB0F1336F78858503B2D35FD7@SI-SRV-Exch.example.local>
MIME-Version: 1.0

Is there a way of fixing this?

Answer (score 1):

Add this X500 address to this user:

```
/O=EXAMPLE_OU=First administrative group/cn=recipients/cn=example1@examplecompany.com
```

Comment: The end of your example is wrong.  It should be /cn=username

Comment: The key is to add the LegacyExchangeDN value as an X500 address on the user object, incorrect syntax in the example or not.